# Generate a action laravel with jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5.6

I development a simple page with a notification modal where will edit and delete  'clients', when i press the edit button i caught the laravel object and obtain data,  i put the data in the field for editing but i Want Generate a action in the form with Jquery . My code is the next:

client.blade

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">Edición de Cliente</h4>

<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="panel-body">
<form data-parsley-validate="true" action="#enter code here" id="update_client" method="get" >
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-group row m-b-15">
<label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Nombre:</label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="nameu" name="name"  data-parsley-required="true" placeholder="Nombre completo" value="" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row m-b-15">
<label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-form-label">NIT/CI:</label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="nitu" name="nit"  data-parsley-type="digits" placeholder="NIT o CI"  data-parsley-required="true" value=""/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row m-b-15">
<label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Teléfono:</label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="telu" name="tel"  data-parsley-type="digits" placeholder="Teléfono"  data-parsley-required="true" value=""/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row m-b-15">
<label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Fax:</label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="faxu" name="fax"  data-parsley-type="digits" placeholder="Fax"  value=""/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row m-b-15">
<label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Celular:</label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="celu" name="cel"  data-parsley-type="digits" placeholder="Celular" value=""  />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row m-b-15">
<label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Dirección:</label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="addru" name="addr"  data-parsley-required="true" placeholder="Dirección"  value=""/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row m-b-15">
<label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Correo Electrónico:</label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="emailu" name="email" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-type="email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" value="" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-save" value="add">Actualizar</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).on("click", "#edit", function(){
             var code = JSON.parse($(this).val());
              $("#nameu").val(code.client_name);
              $("#nitu").val(code.client_nit);
                $("#telu").val(code.client_telephone);
                $("#faxu").val(code.client_fax);
                $("#celu").val(code.client_cellphone);
                $("#addru").val(code.client_address);
                $("#emailu").val(code.client_email);
                var action = "{{action('ClientController@update',[ '$id' => "+code.client_id+"  ])}}";
              $( "#update_client" ).attr( "action", action  );

    });
```

when i press the button in action appears "http://myipserver/client/+code.client_id+"

Comment: you have problem in your action change for url and pass this

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the client_id from your JS in the browser it will not be available to the Laravel action() helper in your blade file.

How about using a straight URL instead of the action() helper?

```
var action = "/client/"+code.client_id;
```

Comment: the logic is the next, i show in the index.blade all my clients on the database and for each client create a button "edit" and "delete". In the edit button put the value key of the array client where is the info of my client. this info caught with the jquery and show if the button edit is press in a notification and in the notification i want modify the client info and save. All of these for each client